Hide repeating tasks in org-agenda's "overdue section"
How would you remove from the "overdue section" (not sure the right name) headings that are scheduled to repeat, e.g.
* TODO My task
SCHEDULED: <2024-04-02 Fri 16:30 .+1w>

this now causes "My task" to appear every day in this section, even though it's only relevant once every week.
Ideally there would be a way to tell org-agenda to ignore only repeating tasks, instead of having to hide them one by one.


Are you sure these should be SCHEDULED tasks? IMO, it does not make much sense to have SCHEDULED repeating tasks at all. Your agenda shoudl include the things that you are working on or will be working on in the span of the agenda (perhaps this week). If you have SCHEDULED items that are 71 days past their start date and they have not been done yet, that's a sign that the item should be reclassified. Hiding them is not going to solve the problem: you might as well unschedule them, mark them as TODO items with some priority and leave them in the backlog.

I recommend Bernt Hansen's writeup on how he uses Org mode, not so much for all the details but more for the guiding principles (aka rules of thumb) he uses to track his projects.

Thanks @NickD I've removed SCHEDULED and left only the timestamp and now the item correctly displays without showing up in that "overdue section" (do you know what it's called?). These items were added automatically by orgzly and I didn't question why they are SCHEDULED. I will need to edit them each time though as I don't see a way to not have them SCHEDULED in orgzly. I need to read up what SCHEDULED means and if there are alternatives.

See Deadline and Scheduling in the manual - instead of clicking, you might want to use Info in Emacs itself: C-h i g(org) RET i Deadline RET.

thanks, one of the curses of using frameworks like doom or spacemacs is that all keybindings are different, so unfortunately this won't work (don't ask how many more hours I've lost because of that)

It's worth finding out how to use Info from whatever framework you are using. Being able to "ask Emacs" is a huge advantage on your Emacs journey.

Agreed, it would have been nicer than trial and error that cost me many many weeks. It would have been very nice...
